# Fill certain cells with value above them

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I have a data range that I would like to transform like this:

```
BEFORE:           AFTER:
PO001808    |PO001808    
PO001808    |PO001808    
FALSE       |PO001808    
FALSE       |PO001808    
FALSE       |PO001808    
PO001845    |PO001845    
PO001845    |PO001845    
PO001845    |PO001845    
FALSE       |PO001845    
FALSE       |PO001845
```

I am trying to fill the cells that have FALSE, with the value above them, then repeat the process when a new value is reached. Do I have to use a VBA formula or is it possible with simple functions?

Comment: You will need VBA. The only way with formulas would be to add a new column which references the 'BEFORE' column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AFTER` column, cell `B2`:

```
=IF($A2=FALSE,$B1,$A2)
```

And drag it down.